# Restore Winamp Window Position

Tags: windows-7, winamp

Winamp has again decided to disappear into a position where I cannot move it. It is the only program that ever does this. Normally I can fix it, and I am determined to fix it without the need to reinstall it.

I am running Windows 7. I have tried switching themes and back again with no dice, however, the other themes are in the correct position, but Winamp remembers the previous position of the Bento theme. I have tried using keyboard move shortcuts, but again, no dice. No move option exists if I right-click the window. I literally cannot move this window using the means that would allow me to move any other window.

Any help in solving this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using another monitor to expand your desktop, you cannot leave Winamp on the secondary monitor before detaching the secondary monitor.

If you have already detached the secondary monitor and you cannot move Winamp back to your primary display, you have to edit the Bento skin configuration (typically located at `C:\%APPDATA%\Winamp\studio.xnf`).

Open `studio.xnf` in Notepad and find these lines (typically around the 23rd line):

```
<entry name="Bento_nomax_x" value="????" />
<entry name="Bento_nomax_y" value="????" />
```

Replace those lines with the following (this will reset the window position to the top-left corner of your primary display):

```
<entry name="Bento_nomax_x" value="0" />
<entry name="Bento_nomax_y" value="0" />
```

Save the file, and open Winamp.

Comment: I attached a secondary monitor & simply moved it so that it was "above" the other monitor in the display settings, this allowed me to grab it as I would any other window.

Answer (score 7):

Deleting studio.xnf also works; it resets all "skin" settings like size and position of all windows (main, playlist, music library, album art).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using "winamp modern" skin like I am, you need to navigate yourself to line `"section name="Container:main">"` in `%AppData%\Winamp\Studio.xnf` and change values in

```
"entry name="rect" value="1,461,1,480" />
 entry name="restoredrect" value="1,461,1,480" />"
```

Comment: Not working for me. Also using modern skin.

Comment: I switched back to classic skin. Position is kept here.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to modify studio.xnf file. Just set you secondary monitor to main and winamp appears. Than you can switch back main monitor and winamp will be still visible.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I went to Winamp preferences → Video and ticked "Synchronise video to screen refresh rate". I tried opening another video file and the video window magically popped up on the primary monitor.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 Winamp 5.8 the file is called Winamp.ini in C:%APPDATA%\Winamp\ .
Delete it, restart you Winamp and the configuration will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

For any window out of screen, in the taskbar, hover the mouse on the program icon, it should show a thumbnail. Right click the thumbnail and choose move, then hit one of the 4 arrow keys. You can now grab your mouse and move the window.

There are other ways to achieve this, like using Alt+Space then "m" when the window is focused (which you can do for instance using Alt+Tab). It's all a matter of getting to activate the "Move" item from the window system menu. That will work with any program that has a system menu.

Comment: This does not work with Winamp. It does not have the normal menu. Nor does Taskbar > Cascade Windows work on it.